# PHP - Multiple functions with SQL queries

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a PHP file with multiple functions that do different queries, example:

```
function getUserEmail($name)
{
    $link=getLink();
    $name=mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $name);
    $output=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link, "SELECT email FROM users WHERE name='$name';"));
    mysqli_close($link);
    return $output[0];
}

function getUserName($id)
{
    $link=getLink();
    $id=mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $id);
    $output=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link, "SELECT name FROM users WHERE id='$id';"));
    mysqli_close($link);
    return $output[0];
}

function getLink()
{
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'myUser', 'myPass');
    mysqli_select_db($link, 'myDB');
    if (!$link) die(mysqli_error($link));
    return $link;
}
```

(this code might not work, it's just an example)

I have it done similar to the example above, but I think because of the many functions being called on a page reload, the multiple DB link creation and closure is not the most efficient way to proceed (and is starting to lag because of the multiple features added to my project).

Ny thought was: creating the $link to the DB on the header of the PHP and saving it to a $_POST var (like $_POST['link']) and then using it through the code, and closing it on the footer.

This would prevent multiple link creations and closures, and I think would improve performance.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Make sure you sanitize the passed variables at some point.

Answer (score 1):

If these functions are part of a class

you can include the `__construct()` and '__destruct()` functions where you deal with database connection. For example:

```
<?php
  class account {
    protected $link;

    function __construct() {
      $link=getLink();
    }

    function __destruct() {
      mysqli_close($link);
    }

    function getUserEmail($name)
    {
      $name=mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $name);
      $output=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link, "SELECT email FROM users WHERE name='$name';"));
      return $output[0];
    }

    function getUserName($id)
    {
      $id=mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $id);
      $output=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link, "SELECT name FROM users WHERE id='$id';"));
      return $output[0];
    }

    function getLink()
    {
      $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'myUser', 'myPass');
      mysqli_select_db($link, 'myDB');
      if (!$link) die(mysqli_error($link));
      return $link;
    }
  }
```

That way you don't have to worry about reopening the connection and closing it. The connection automatically opens when the account object is created and it automatically closes when the account object is no longer being referenced.

Read more about [constructors and destructors here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php).

Additionally, as suggested in the comments, you could include a broad `getUser()` method so that you wouldn't have to query the database for all of the user's separate entries. It would elliminate the amount of times you interacted with the database and would be a more efficient way to deal with the data. Like so:

```
function getUser($id)
{
  $id=mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $id);
  $output=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id';"));
  return $output;
}
```

Comment: That's also a good way, but I'm not using OOP, I'm doing procedural code instead.

Comment: I assume you still have some initial function you call, or even the main function to load the content for the homepage. In that function you could call `getLink()` and assign it to `$link` as a global variable, it would be a similar concept.

Comment: Well ok but i wouldnt do what youre doing... you should just have one function called `getUser` that returns the array of user data, then access it by key. Its silly to keep hitting the DB for every piece of info.

Comment: yeah, that's what I was thinking, I have a file with the initial includes, I'd do the getLink() there and assign it as global or assign it to a superglobal var like $_POST['link'] and then use it throughout the code and close it at the finish

Comment: If you're interested @Wold - I made some improvements to your OOP style here: http://shrib.com/moQlDxiP

Comment: I updated my answer. If you aren't using OOP, you could still use the broad `getUser()` method and eliminate the amount of times you interact with the database.

Comment: While the destructor might be good practice in general, PHP will close the connection automagically at the end of the script so it may not be necessary.

Comment: Personally that sounds like a horrible idea (the procedural route) in that OOP is my personal preference and makes for an easier time managing things. I mean you dont have to go super overboard with your architecture, but even just using classes as a collection of functions and minimal state handling is going to make things much easier.

Comment: @prodigitalson I get how OOP is better than procedural, and I use it on many of other languages, but on PHP I don't really see how it helps, because creating and storing "objects" for something that lives less than a second... it's not really helpful imho.

Comment: @DarkW for encapsulation and state management during that lifetime. Just because the Request/Response lifecyle is short and things only live for that cycle doesn't negate the face that you need to manage state and interactions during it.

Comment: @DarkW There a lot of benefits to not only using OOP, but MVC. A lot of the issues your having, like database connectivity, would be inherently dealt with in an MVC framework. yes procedural is good when you simply want to execute a script serever-side, but there are some really light MVC frameworks that exist that IMO are really easy to work with.

Comment: I might give it a try on future projects on in case this project outgrows procedural style eheh, but for now it would needlessly overcomplicate the project

Answer (score 1):

Use a global

```
$link=false;
function getLink()
    {
      global $link;
      if (!$link) {
      $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'myUser', 'myPass');
      mysqli_select_db($link, 'myDB');
      if (!$link) die(mysqli_error($link));
      }
      return $link;
    }
```

This way, the first call to `getLink()` establishes a connection, and all subsequent calls simply re-use the connection established by the first call. After making this change, you can keep the rest of your code the same. Being able to use OOP I think is actually a great benefit of using `mysqli` over `mysql`, but if you don't want to use OOP this should do it for you.